# Why is csrss.exe running 169 times?

Tags: windows, 64-bit, process, task-manager

When I noticed that opening many tabs (10 to 20) in Google Chrome took an increased time with every new one I looked into Process Hacker and discovered 169 `csrss.exe` processes. I've never seen that many before, what could be the cause and is it a problem?

See my [list of processes](http://pastebin.com/uSCDxqS1) and [System Information using DxDiag](http://pastebin.com/YNWpf8Gu).

Edit: When restarting Windows I noticed that there were updates pending to be installed, not sure if that's related. After restarting I only have `csrss.exe` running two times, back to normal I guess. Looking at the Event Log didn't reveal anything either.

Answer (score 1):

Some process is launching all these `csrss.exe` instances, figure out which.

You can sort them into a process tree using [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653), then figure out the parent of them.

Comment: I used [Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/) which displays even more information and it showed the `csrss.exe` processes as top level nodes in its tree.

Comment: @magnoz: Can you try to sort them by `PID` and tell me the lowest numbers, the process that launched them will have a lower `PID` than the majority of them so that is another way to figure it out. What is that `conhost.exe` doing there? Can you see the command line that was used to launch those `csrss.exe` processes? As a side note, Process Explorer actually displays more information but you have to turn the individual columns on. Enabling all those relevant might give further clues, perhaps looking into the thread information to see which functions were called too...

Comment: Thx for the hint with PIDs, I'll keep that in mind. Luckily/unfortunately I can't reproduce the problem - as soon as I restarted everything has been back to normal since (csrss is only running two times now). And as for the conhost I currently have it running three times, all having csrss as parent. But I don't have any console window opened...

Comment: @magnoz: Then you might want to investigate these. See if Process Explorer / Process Hacker provides you with more information, or you could look at all the various things that can load on boot using [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902).